# QVector Append Crashing

Tags: c++, qt

I have a data tracking program with qt which takes in information from the gui and appends it to my class which holds the data. I did not use QVector2d because there does not seem to be any `.append` method, and I have searched the help forums and docs for qt. I have to use a QObject because I will be serializing the information. The data is stored in a nested QVector like so 
`QVector< QVector<qint8> > log_matrix;`

For some reason, when I append a `QVector<qint8>` to the nested `QVector< QVector<qint8>>` the program crashes and I get no helpful debugging information.
I have tried this as a method to the data class in my header:

```
void insert_new_log(QVector<qint8> new_log)
{
    this->log_matrix.append(new_log);
}
```

and have tried this in the main.cpp file

```
QVector<qint8> my_data;
//initialize data
my_class->my_data_matrix.append(my_data);
```

Am I misusing the append method? is there another way to do this that doesn't use the append method?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Nothing obvious in the provided code snippets. Make sure the calling instance is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have forgotten the class name in your method definition. In any case, your method should work.

```
void ClassName::insert_new_log(QVector<qint8> new_log)
{
    this->log_matrix.append(new_log);
}
```

Your second example does not initialize my_data with any data. Although it certainly will work, it is traditionally bad form to access public members of a class externally. I would recommend using getters/setters. For the sake of illustration I used `this` instead of your `my_class`

You can also use the append operator `<<` to invoke the `append` method if you like.

```
QVector< QVector<qint8> > log_matrix;
QVector<qint8> my_data;

my_data<<1;
this->my_data_matrix<<(my_data);
```